# Groovy: what is better when increasing date, + operator or .plus() method?

Tags: date, groovy

Though both the option does the same job but we have them both in groovy, so is there any complexity difference between them or anything else which can promote me to strictly use the operator or the method?

```
Date date = new Date()
​assert date + 20 == date.plus(20)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference if you use `date + 20` or `date.plus(20)`, because Groovy supports [operators overloading](http://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#Operator-Overloading). `+` operator for `java.util.Date` class is implemented in [`DateGroovyMethods.plus(date, days)`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/org/codehaus/groovy/runtime/DateGroovyMethods.html#plus-java.util.Date-int-) and both expressions trigger this method.